# How do I do calendar arithmetic with java.util.Date?

Tags: java

Currently I have a Date object representing a time. How would I add 5 minutes to this object?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

You could use [`Calendar`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), which will make it easy to add any length of time:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTime(date);
cal.add(Calendar.MINUTE, 5);
Date newDate = cal.getTime();
```

For your case you could just add the time in milliseconds like this:

```
Date newDate = new Date(date.getTime() + 5 * 60 * 1000L);
```

Answer (score 9):

Consider using [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/). It is a library that makes date and time handling far more pleasant than the built-in ones.

The [`DateTime`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html) class offers a [`plusMinutes`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html#plusMinutes(int)) method.

```
DateTime now = DateTime.now( DateTimeZone.forID( "America/Montreal" ) );
DateTime inFiveMinutes = now.plusMinutes( 5 );
```

Comment: And is completely overkill for such a simple task.

Comment: @Heiko: not if you do a lot of such simple tasks.

Comment: @HeikoRupp If someone is manipulating date-time values by adding minutes, they are probably doing many other date-time tasks. Those seemingly simple tasks quickly become complicated, confusing, error-prone, and difficult to debug without a decent date-time library such as [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) or the [java.time package](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) in Java 8 (inspired by Joda-Time, defined by [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310)).

Comment: FYI, the [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project is now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advising migration to the [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes. See [Tutorial by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 6):

With Java 8 there are new options.  In fact Joda Time recommends moving to Java 8 Date and Time APIs as soon as possible.  Here is an example of adding time from this link:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/iso/period.html

The following code adds 5 minutes to the current time:

```
LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now();
now = now.plusMinutes(5);
System.out.println(now);
```

Comment: `LocalDateTime` is the wrong class for this purpose as it purposely has no concept of time zone.

Comment: Not true, check out the original question.

Comment: @JeremyBunn The Question asks about a `java.util.Date`. That class represents a moment in UTC. In contrast, the `LocalDateTime` class does not. `LocalDateTime` purposely lacks any concept of time zone of offset-from-UTC, therefore **`LocalDateTime` cannot represent a moment**. In *java.time*, the equivalent to `java.util.Date` is `java.time.Instant`. Thus the presence of the new `Date::toInstant()` conversion method added to that old class. I cannot imagine any situation in which calling `LocalDateTime.now()` is the right thing to do.

Answer (score 5):

Date has the time in milli-seconds.  However, you might find using a `long` is simpler for this type of calculations.

```
Date date1 = new Date();
long time1 = date1.getTime();
long time2 = time1 + 5 * 60 * 1000;
Date date2 = new Date(time2);
```

If you use plain `long` you can drop the lines with Date objects.

Answer (score 4):

## tl;dr

```
myDate.toInstant()
      .plus( 5 , ChronoUnit.MINUTES )
```

## You don’t

The `Date` class is part of the troublesome old date-classes that should no longer be used. They are supplanted by the java.time classes.

## `Instant`

Convert your `Date` to an `Instant` using new method added to the old class. Both represent a moment on the timeline in UTC but the newer class has a finer resolution of nanoseconds.

```
Instant instant = myDate.toInstant() ;
```

Adding five minutes is easy.

```
Instant later = instant.plus( 5 , ChronoUnit.MINUTES ) ;
```

Or use a `Duration`.

```
Duration d = Duration.ofMinutes( 5 ) ;
Instant later = instant.plus( d ) ;
```

Answer (score 0):

In Java 7 you might use DateUtils class from [Apache Commons](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/index.html) library:

```
Date dateWithFiveMinutesAdded = DateUtils.addMinutes(date, 5);
```

or [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) Library:

```
Date dateWithFiveMinutesAdded = new DateTime(date).plusMinutes(5).toDate();
```

If you use Java 8 and you don't want to use any external libraries consider new built in Java 8 Date/Time API:

```
Date dateWithFiveMinutesAdded = Date.from(date.toInstant().plus(5, ChronoUnit.MINUTES));
```

or alternatively:

```
Date dateWithFiveMinutesAdded = Date.from(date.toInstant().plusSeconds(5 * 60));
```

However with Java 8 you should use rather Instant, ZonedDateTime or LocalDateTime instead of Date.

Obviously there are many more ways to do it, but in my opinion those are quite clean and compact when it comes to code clearness.

Comment: `LocalDateTime` is the wrong class for this purpose as it purposely has no concept of time zone.

Comment: `Date` also has no concept of time zone. Converting it to `LocalDateTime` and backwards with `ZoneOffset.UTC (+0)` doesn't change time zone so everything looks fine for me. Can you give an example of situation in which something will go wrong with this conversion?

Comment: Incorrect, `java.util.Date` *does* have a concept of time zone: UTC. A `Date` is a count from the first moment of 1970 in UTC (ignoring leap seconds). So **a `Date` is always in UTC**, and represents a specific point on the timeline. A `LocalDateTime` has no association with any zone or offset, and does *not* represent a moment on the timeline. So while the numerical representation of the date-time might work out, the semantics of your solution is wrong. The replacement in java.time for `java.util.Date` is `Instant`, not `LocalDateTime` nor `ZonedDateTime`.

Comment: For more discussion, see: [Java 8: What's the difference between Instant and LocalDateTime?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32437550/642706)

Comment: My bad. Edited.