# Add hours and Minutes to a certain time java

Tags: java, time

I have  `String initialTime= "10:30:00"`
I am converting it into time like so:-

```
DateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss");
Date date = sdf.parse(initialTime);
Time time = new Time(date.getTime());
int initHour = time.getHours()
int initMind = time.getMinutes();
```

Further I have two values;

```
int hour, mins;
```

The hour value can be anything from 0-10;
mins value can be 0,15,30,45.

The user selects a time by selecting `hour` and `mins`. As soon as the user selects the values they should get added to the  `initialTime`and shown in `finalTIme`

So if:-

```
hour=0 and mins=15 then finalTIme=10:45:00
hour=0 and mins=35 then finalTIme=11:00:00
hour=0 and mins=45 then finalTIme=11:15:00
```

I tried doing something like:-

```
if(hour==0 && mins==0)
{
    finalTime = initialTime;
}

else if(hour==0 && mins>0 && mins <30)
{
   mins = initMins + mins 
}
else if(hour==0 && mins>0 && mins >=30)
{
   hours = hours+1;
   mins = mins-60;
}
```

But I did not get the required output. HOw can I do it in a less complicated manner?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java : how to add 10 mins in my Time](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9015536/java-how-to-add-10-mins-in-my-time) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5894726/642706) and many others.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use java.util.Calendar class:

```
DateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss");
Date date = sdf.parse(initialTime);
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTime(date);

cal.add(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hours);
cal.add(Calendar.MINUTE, minutes);

date = cal.getTime();
```

You might also consider the new Date API from JDK 8.

Comment: This will update the current time right? I want to add to my initial time of 10.30