# How can I get many integers as variables from a String?

Tags: java, parsing

I want to make a code that validates a birthdate,

I would like to make 3 different variables:

Let's say the user writes down "12/6/1993".

int DD = 12, int MM = 6, int YYYY = 1993.

So I can make if statements to work with them as calculable numbers.

These variables would have to be taken from the single string that the user puts.

```
package practice;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Practice {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter a date as DD/MM/YYYY: ");

        String date = scanner.next();

        System.out.println(date);

       }

    }
```

I know that I have to use Parse for this, but all of the content that I searched on the Internet does not show me how to get the numbers inside a string as separate, just altogether.

Comment: There are two different things you need to do. The search terms you're looking for are `split` and `Integer.parseInt`

Comment: I'm not so sure about that. It's a lot easier to use [a parser specifically for dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/999172/how-to-parse-a-date).

Comment: @Jorn depends on the context. For example if this is homework and splitting + parsing is the point of the exercise then using a parser for date may defeat the purpose of the exercise. Since OP didn't specify I'd keep both doors opened.

Comment: "So I can make if statements to work with [dates]". Sounds like an XY problem to me. How about [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5894745/1707353)?

Answer (score 3):

Use [LocalDate](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDate.html) and [DateTimeFormatter](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) from the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) package
Try it like this.

```
System.out.println("Enter a date as DD/MM/YYYY: ");
String date = scanner.next();
LocaldDate ld = LocalDate.parse(date,DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy"));
System.out.println(ld);
 
int day = ld.getDayOfMonth();
int month = ld.getMonthValue();
int year = ld.getYear();

System.out.println(day + " " + month + " " + year);
```

For `"22/10/2023"` prints

```
2023-10-22
22 10 2023
```

You could also use split.

```
String[] vals = date.split("/");

int day = Integer.parseInt(vals[0]);
int month = Integer.parseInt(vals[1]);
int year = Integer.parseInt(vals[2]);
```

Some dates will be auto corrected by default.  To avoid a date like `"31/06/1993"` from being corrected to `"30/06/1993"`, use `DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy") .withResolverStyle(ResolverStyle.STRICT)` which would result in a `DateTimeParseException` that would need to be appropriately handled.  Using `ResolverStyle.LENIENT` would wrap the above example to `"01/07/1993"`.

Comment: This may result in invalid/wrong integers in some rare cases. Use `"31/06/1993"` as input, which will be parsed but will also result in a `LocalDate` with the value `30` for the day of month! At least it does on my machine…

Comment: @deHaar I agree.  There is a lot more to this in terms of validation of the input.  I was just providing the basics for the OP.  In fact, using your example and specifying `ResolverStyle.LENIENT`, it takes that to be "01/07/1993".  I will put in a note to use ResolverStyle.STRICT to catch meaningless dates.

Comment: I didn't apply any `ResolverStyle`, but good to know that doing so even introduces a certain variance to the results… I'll check if I can find a `ResolverStyle` that throws an `Exception`. Found one: `ResolverStyle.STRICT` should do.

Comment: @deHaar Yep.  I had already posted that in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example.

Utilize the *[String#split](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String))* method, to divide the *String* into a *String* *array*.
Then, assign each variable, *DD*, *MM*, and *YYYY*, to the corresponding value.

```java
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
String s = in.nextLine(), ss[] = s.split("/");
int DD = Integer.parseInt(ss[0]),
    MM = Integer.parseInt(ss[1]),
    YYYY = Integer.parseInt(ss[2]);
```

Alternately, use another *Scanner* instance, to iterate the values.

```java
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in),
        s = new Scanner(in.nextLine()).useDelimiter("/");
int DD = s.nextInt(), MM = s.nextInt(), YYYY = s.nextInt();
```

Or, use the *[StringTokenizer](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/StringTokenizer.html)* class.

```java
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
StringTokenizer s = new StringTokenizer(in.nextLine(), "/");
int DD = Integer.parseInt(s.nextToken()),
    MM = Integer.parseInt(s.nextToken()),
    YYYY = Integer.parseInt(s.nextToken());
```

Output

```
11/20/2023
DD = 11
MM = 20
YYYY = 2023
```

On a final note, sometimes date values are entered with other delimiters, i.e., `.`, `-`, and space.
For this, you'll need to use a *[regular expression pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression)*.

Here is an example.

```java
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
String s = in.nextLine(), ss[] = s.split("[/.-]|[ \\t]+");
int DD = Integer.parseInt(ss[0]),
    MM = Integer.parseInt(ss[1]),
    YYYY = Integer.parseInt(ss[2]);
System.out.println("DD = " + DD);
System.out.println("MM = " + MM);
System.out.println("YYYY = " + YYYY);
```